# What does mOffsetMatrix actually do in Assimp?

Tags: c++, opengl, assimp

I am quite sure that mOffsetMatrix transforms vertex from mesh space to bone space, which is confirmed by this one
http://assimp.sourceforge.net/lib_html/structai_bone.html

But then I saw this, which says that it actually transforms vertices from bone space to mesh space.
https://github.com/assimp/assimp/pull/1803

Now I am very confused. So what exactly does mOffsetMatrix do?

Answer (score 8):

The **offsetMatrix** of a bone is the **inverse of that bone's global transform at bind pose**. In other words, if you traverse the bone/node hierarchy, applying the local transform (*mTransformation* in Assimp) of each bone/node hierarchically to its children, we get the global transform for each bone/node. The **inverse** of this matrix for a particular bone equals its offsetMatrix. As implied here, it can be computed manually - regardless, it is constant and should not be computed per frame.

The name "offsetMatrix", though somewhat confusing (something like **inverseBind** would be clearer), probably comes from its use. The transform we use for skinning is (**B_keyframe * offsetMatrix**), where **B_keyframe** is the global transformation of a bone at some target location, provided e.g. by an animation clip. This composite transformation is effectively an *offset*, from bind pose (where the mesh vertices are defined) to B_keyframe. When applied to vertices, (B_keyframe * offsetMatrix) will "move" vertices, from bind positions to whatever position B_keyframe transforms to.
Note that if B_keyframe is equal to the bind transform, e.g. computed from the skeleton's mTransformation:s as above, then (B_keyframe * offsetMatrix) is identity and vertices will not move from their original positions in bind pose.

I personally favour the "from mesh space to bone space" definition when it comes to offsetMatrix. Why? Because the inverse of offsetMatrix - the (global) bone transform (at bind pose) - is most intuitively understood as a **transformation from bone to mesh/model space**. Inverting back, offsetMatrix transforms **from mesh/model space to bone space**.
Compare with the View matrix in rendering: it is the inverse of the camera's world transform (T*R), and is generally understood to transform from world to view space.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer for your question ( coming from a solution from the bug ):

> it depends how you think of the transform. If the matrix
>   multiplications come after the point (i.e point * transform with point
>   being a "row" vector) then it makes sense to say it converts from
>   "mesh space to bone space", as it takes a point in mesh space and
>   outputs a point in bone space. But when using matrix premultiplication
>   as assimp does (tranform * point with point being a "column" vector)
>   it makes more sense to think of it as transforming the space itself,
>   from "bone space to mesh space", whereupon the point in mesh space can
>   be used.
>
> This is why the original poster is confused, because they are thinking
>   about it backwards compared to how assimp treats point transformation.
>   This is probably leading directly to their confusion with working out
>   the transformation matrix of the bone and thinking this should be the
>   same as mOffsetMatrix, when in fact it is the inverse.
>
> This is all especially confusing as DirectX uses postmultiplication,
>   and OpenGL uses premultiplication.
>
> This all said, i hope that someone can update the documentation so
>   that it makes it clear for everybody. It's very difficult to specify
>   clearly without an "official" way of thinking about this sort of
>   thing. I can't even find it documented anywhere how assimp treats
>   transformation matrix multiplication... although the matrix notation
>   used on the "Data Structures" page of the assimp docs implies
>   premultiplication with column vectors.

Hope that this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is wrong. So I need to update our doc. See [issue 1950](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/issues/1950)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just want to clear something up. I try to calculate the inverse bind pose matrix by concatenating y concatenating all the mTransformation starting from scene->rootNode to each bone in question. The result I get is different from mOffsetMatrix, which from my understanding, shouldn't be. Is this expected?

Comment: I would love to know the answer to that question.